# Jquery else if statement not working to toggle class no-scroll-1

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm really sorry for asking such a basic question, but i've tried a couple of things and my else if is still not working.

so I'm trying create this if else function:

**first part**

when any of the **.mega-menu-link** (parent) is clicked

the function will look for a class called **.show** in one of its child called **.megamenu-item** (child)

**second part**

when any of the **.mega-menu-link** is clicked, but after searching classList, **.megamenu-item** does not have **.show** I would like to enable scrolling on the HTML tag.

I have managed to get first part working but second part seems to get ignored, this is what i have so far

```
...
...

<li class="nav-item mega-menu-link">
    <span id="headingThree">
        <a href="" class="nav-link mega-menu-a" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#megamenu3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="megamenu3">
            Partners<i class="fa-regular fa-angle-down"></i>
        </a>
    </span>
    <div class="megamenu-item accordion-collapse collapse in" id="megamenu3" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#MegaMenuDestop">
        <div class=" shadow megamenu bg-white ">`</div>
    </div>
</li>

...
..
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.classList = function() {return this[0].className.split(/\s+/);};
    $(".mega-menu-link").click(function() {
         if($(this).children(".megamenu-item").classList(".show")) {
            $("html").addClass("no-scroll-1");
            console.log("no scroll");
        }
        else if(!$(this).children(".megamenu-item").classList(".show")){
            $("html").removeClass("no-scroll-1");
            console.log("scroll");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think the `.classList` extension that you have added to the jQuery prototype works the way you think it does. It appears to return an array containing each class belonging to the element against which it is applied. It doesn't do anything with any parameters it is called with, so the `.show` you are passing in `$(this).children(".megamenu-item").classList(".show")` won't do anything. The jQuery API has an [.addClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method, which looks like it does what you want.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, but i'm trying to find a way for the function to search if the .show class exist in the child div when parent div is clicked. and if it is there, add the .no-scroll-1 class to the html, if it isn't, remove the .no-scroll-1 class

Comment: You can simply replace the ```.classList(".show")``` from every if/else if statement with ```.hasClass("show")``` or even just ```.is(":visible")```.

Comment: Try this JSFiddle (with ```.hasClass("show")```) https://jsfiddle.net/go9u0nek/5/.

Comment: Hi @timonwimmer thanks for the help!, the only issue is that when i click the same .mega-menu-link for the second time and not it's siblings. the html should be scrollable too. is there a way around this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean, but I think you want to also toggle the .show class of the children of the clicked .mega-menu-link. 
Take a look at this JSFiddle and tell me if it's what you need! https://jsfiddle.net/f5oxwnc0/4/

Answer (score -1):

What I was trying to get across in my comment is that the extension to the jQuery prototype you added does not behave in a compatible manner to the way you are trying to use it.

```
$.fn.classList = function() {return this[0].className.split(/\s+/);};
```

This returns the class names on the applicable element split into an array. For example, if called on an element that looks like `<div class="megamenu-item accordion-collapse collapse in">`, it will return the array: `["megamenu-item", "accordion-collapse", "collapse", "in"]`. Invoking this method with an argument, as in `.classList(".show")` does nothing to change what is returned because the method body does nothing with argument passed to it.

jQuery's [.hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method seems to have the behavior you desire. However,  I would recommend a different approach.

All you need to do is *toggle* the "show" class on the `.megamenu-item` child of the clicked parent. jQuery has a [.toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className) method for that:

```
$(this).find('.megamenu-item').toggleClass("show");
```

I think the second part of your post wants to disable scrolling by adding a class to the `<html>` element when *any* `.megamenu-item` has the "show" class.

If this is the case, it won't be enough just to look at the `.megamenu-item` child of the `.mega-menu-link` that was clicked. Instead, you would need to look at *all* `.mega-menu-link` elements to determine if have the "show" class. This could be done with the selector: `.mega-menu-link .megamenu-item.show`. And we would use the length of that result set to determine if the "no-scroll-1" class should be applied to `<html>`.

The resultant code looks like:

```
$(".mega-menu-link").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".megamenu-item").toggleClass("show");
  const canScroll = $(".mega-menu-link .megamenu-item.show").length === 0;
  $('html').toggleClass("no-scroll-1", !canScroll);
});
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/wzx890vm/) for reference.